# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Error could not open file "base/16384/19048": No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, vacuum, autovacuum

Few of the tables and indexes are bloated though auto vacuum has enables.

Two reclaim the space vacuum, I have ran vacuum full on the larger tables and also performed reindex on the indexes which are in larger size. Now the size of the database is in control.

After perfoming the vacuum full and reindexing on larger tables, I am facing below error.

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Error could not open file "base/16384/19048": No such file or directory

Please guide me how to resolve the above error and let me know does this has any relation with vacumm full or reindexing operation which are performed by me.

Answer (score 0):

You should connect to the database with the OID 16384 and find out what that file is:

```
SELECT oid::regclass FROM pg_class WHERE relfilenode = 19048;
```

The error should be independent of `VACUUM` or `REINDEX` runs. Did you experience OS crashes recently?

The error indicates data corruption; a file is missing in your data directory.

The easiest option is to restore from backup.

Other than that, you can delete the object that belongs to the missing file to restore integrity (while potentially suffering data loss).